# What's "apoplectic popping noises"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> She was entirely round, now, like a vast life buoy with piggy eyes, and her hands and feet stuck out weirdly as she drifted up into the air, making **apoplectic popping noises**.

What's "apoplectic popping noises"? What does it sound like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angry popping noises. Apoplectic has two meanings: (1) medical: relating to apoplexy (a stroke) (2) derived from that, extremely angry (a person can be so angry they resemble someone having a stroke). "Pop/popping" is onomatopoeic, and 'apoplectic' reinforces that. It would sound like someone making "p... p... p..." sounds with their lips.

[Apoplectic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apoplectic)

[Onomatopoeia](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/onomatopoeia)

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is as good as ours.  I've never heard the sound of an aunt being inflated.

The meanings of the words in that expression are literal "apoplectic" means "very angry" (and Harry's aunt was furious).  Popping is the sound made when air escapes from something and sounds like "pop".

She made the sound like a very angry person makes when magically filled with gas.